How to vectorize trace on an array of 2d matrices?
I am trying to set up some YALMIP constraints as follows:
for i=1:q 
    Constraints = [Constraints, trace(As(:, :, i)) == 1]
end

So I am essentially just trying to assert that all the (square) matrices in the first q pages of the 3d array As have trace 1.
How do I vectorize this so that I don't have to keep resizing my Constraints array?

You should just preallocate the array.

@CrisLuengo I don’t think that’s possible, see the second comment by the developer of YALMIP: https://groups.google.com/g/yalmip/c/w2FK3jTgl9A

I don’t know what they did to implement this constraint class, but if you can’t preallocate an array, that’s because they didn’t implement the appropriate function. Preallocation should always be possible in MATLAB. Also, a = [a, 0] is the worst way to grow an array in MATLAB, because every iteration all the data has to be copied over. a(end+1) = 0 is much better, as MATLAB will double the underlying storage when necessary, so there’s a whole lot less copying that way. See this Q&A.

As Cris Luengo said, to avoid resizing you don't need to vectorize, it suffices to preallocate.
But if you want to vectorize, here's a way, using linear indexing:
As = randn(4,4,3); % example data
m = size(As, 1); % number of rows. The number of columns should be the same
q = size(As, 3); % number of pages
ind = (1:m+1:m^2).' + (0:q-1)*m^2; % linear index. Each diagonal is a column
Constraints = sum(As(ind), 1) == 1;

The linear indexing part works as follows. Consider a 4×4×3 example array ( As). Displaying its 3 pages (third-dimension slices) separately, the linear order of the entries is
 1     5     9    13
 2     6    10    14
 3     7    11    15
 4     8    12    16

17    21    25    29
18    22    26    30
19    23    27    31
20    24    28    32

33    37    41    45
34    38    42    46
35    39    43    47
36    40    44    48

The line lin = ... first builds the column vector
 1
 6
11
16

which corresponds to the diagonal of the first page. Then, the row vector [0 16 32] is added to that column vector. Thanks to implicit expansion, this produces the following matrix of linear indices (variable lin):
 1    17    33
 6    22    38
11    27    43
16    32    48

As can be seen, each column contains the indices of the diagonal of a page from the original array. The last line of the code applies this matrix as an index, computes the sum of each column and compares with 1.

Please see my reply to Chris Luengo’s comment.

@gen Sorry, I’m not sure what the thread you link is about. But if you want to vectorize trace computation (compute all traces at once) you can use my code

Can you please add some more explanation for the last two lines?

@gen Done. Please see edited answer
